# ngIf still renders div on false condition

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

I am trying to show a series of material cards based on a flag in my data. If the flag is falsy, I'm still getting an empty div (and thus extra space) injected into the DOM.

Assume I have an array of `Fruit` objects that have an `isBanana` flag. My template looks like:

```html
<div *ngIf="fruit$ | async as fruits">
  <!-- NOT bananas -->
  <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <mat-card *ngIf="!fruit.isBanana" [fruit]="fruit"></mat-card>
  </div>

  <!-- Bananas -->
  <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <mat-card *ngIf="fruit.isBanana" [fruit]="fruit"></mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I realize it's not ideal to loop through the array twice, but due headers/sections in my actual application, that's just kinda the way it has to be.

Anyhoo, the final render in the browser is such that, in the first/non-banana section, I successfully get cards without bananas, but each time that for loop comes across a fruit object that's *not* a banana, it injects an empty div, which adds space between cards where there should not be, such as

```html
<div class="ng-star-inserted">
  <div>
    <mat-card><!-- card template --></mat-card>
  </div>
  <div><!-- literally just an empty div --></div>
</div>
```

I would think that if the condition is false, *nothing* would be rendered, but clearly that's not the case.

Comment: Move `ngif` to the div, use the expanded version of `ngfor` wrapping the div https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: @ArleighHix unfortunately I can't do this. Using the long form, `let-i` to address the individual items of the array is only available when the container is an `ng-template`. Due to my styling classes, I am required to use `div` as the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the conditional on the `<mat-card>`, so only this element gets removed. To remove the wrapping `<div>` you need to put the `*ngIf` on the `<div>` element. Since you cannot have two structural directives on one element, you will have to wrap the `<div>` with `<ng-container>` and move the `*ngFor` there. `<ng-container>` won't be added to the DOM, so you'll end up with the same structure as you would without it.

```
<div *ngIf="fruit$ | async as fruits">
  <!-- NOT bananas -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <div *ngIf="!fruit.isBanana">
      <mat-card [fruit]="fruit"></mat-card>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Bananas -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <div *ngIf="fruit.isBanana">
      <mat-card [fruit]="fruit"></mat-card>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I actually arrived at this solution before seeing your answer, so I will accept this as the solution. However, for my specific use case/with the specific global styling I'm using, I *have to* use the `div` instead of the `ng-container`. I ended up moving everything within the async `div` to a sub-component as an `@Input()` where I was able to process the fruits in the TypeScript file into two separate arrays before displaying it. Alternatively I could have maybe done this in the observable's `pipe`, but that would have been clunky and difficult to test.